# Telerik MVC Grid with check all checkbox not functioning

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I know my code is right but am I missing some script because the Telerik MVC grid "check all checkboxes" is not functioning? I'm using jquery-1.7.1.min.js

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<RenanNewTask.Models.RenanListViewModel>()
    .Name("RenanGrid")
    .DataKeys(dataKeys => dataKeys.Add(c => c.Org_UID))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        //columns.Bound(c => c.eff_date).Title("Effective Date").Format("{0:MM/dd   /yyyy}").Width(20);
        columns.Bound(c => c.eff_date).Title("Effective Date").ReadOnly(true).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(20).Encoded(true)
            .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='checkedRecords' value='<#= eff_date #>' />")
            .HeaderTemplate(
                    @<text>
                        <input type="checkbox" title="check all records" id="checkAllRecords" />
                    </text>
        )
        .Title("")
        .Width(10)
        .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" })
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" });
        columns.Bound(o => o.eff_date).Width(20);
        columns.Bound(c => c.name_long).Title("Name Long").Width(20);
    })
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
        .Select("GetOrgUID", "Renan"))
    .Pageable(paging => paging.Style((GridPagerStyles.PageInput | GridPagerStyles.Numeric | GridPagerStyles.PageSizeDropDown | GridPagerStyles.NextPrevious)).Position(GridPagerPosition.Bottom).PageTo(1).PageSize(20))
    .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Height(250))
    .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
)
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" lanuage="javascript">   
    $('#checkAllRecords').click(function checkAll() {
        $("#RenanGrid tbody input:checkbox").attr("checked", this.checked);
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: cc @RickL In case you have the same question, I posted an answer. I didn't notice it is an very old question you edited.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons could be, that you are to early. The checkbox you want to attach an event might not be inserted into the DOM at that time.

Wrap your code into the ready event:

```
$(function() {
    $('#checkAllRecords').click(function checkAll() {
        $("#RenanGrid tbody input:checkbox").attr("checked", this.checked);
    });
});
```

Not sure, why you are using `jquery-1.7.1`, which is seriously outdated. A year or two ago, Kendo UI migrated to jquery 3. I was gone through hell at that time, since they introduced some `kendo.syncReady`. I am not sure, if this is related to your problem. I worked arround moving the initialization logic at the end of the eventstack via `setTimeout`:

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#checkAllRecords').click(function checkAll() {
            $("#RenanGrid tbody input:checkbox").attr("checked", this.checked);
        });
    });
});
```